# how to receive the response of coming from the API specified with the url attribute of p-fileUpload?

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, primeng

I've got this control:

```
<p-fileUpload url="http://localhost:8586/upload"
              (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"
              multiple="multiple">
```

The api at `http://localhost:8586/upload` returns `{key:value}` after the file is uploaded. How can I access this response of the api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same component which the html belongs to, write the method to track the output event by the 'p-fileupload' component/library.

Example way would be -

```
public onUpload(event): void {
  // access key value here. probably event.key
  const key = event.key;
}
```

Comment: ```event.originalEvent.body``` Is that the event you need to capture? And, did this answer help you?